# Formal definition of "class" in ZF?

Tags: set-theory

The lecture notes  "Lectures in set theory with a particular emphasis on the Method of Forcing" by Thomas Jech define a *class* as:

> Generally, we call a class the collection of all sets $x$ satisfying a formula $\phi(x, \vec u)$ where $\vec u$ are some sets (parameters). We use the notation $x \in C \leftrightarrow \phi(x, \vec u)$ and $C = \{ x : \phi(x, \vec u)\}$

While the above seems like a good informal definition, it doesn't actually tell me what a class *is*. **Axiomatically**, what is a class in ZF?

The book continues to say:

> Two classes, $C = \{ x : \phi(x, \vec u) \}$ and $D = \{ x: \psi(x, \vec v) \}$ are considered equal if for all $x$, $\phi(x, u) \leftrightarrow \phi(x, v)$.

I don't follow how we write the expression *for all $x$*. In particular, **what is $x$ ranging over**? $\forall x \in \texttt{what}?$

---

Definition of class:

[image]

Equality of two classes:

[image]

Comment: Why are you reading lecture notes from half a century ago?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Because I wanted a fast way to learn forcing, and the lecture notes promised me exactly that :) Do you have more up to date suggestions?

Comment: Halbeisen's book, Kunen's old book, Kunen's new book, Jech's set theory book (3rd edition), Džamonja's very recent book (called "Fast Track to Forcing"), Weaver's book, and probably a few others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, it is not uncommon to define class as a synonym for a formula of the form $\phi(x,\vec u)$, as used in your informal definition. It is not a huge mental step to informally couple a formula to the collection of sets that satisfy the formula, and it much more concrete to think about collections rather than formulas.

> In particular, **what is $x$ ranging over**? $\forall x \in \texttt{what}?$

For all $x$ in your universe of sets. Which is again a class, given by, say, the formula $x=x$.